# How to access json result object when normal access seem to fail?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON result object returned from an ajax request and am trying to access it. I can see the object in the developer console but however I try to access it I get "undefined".

This is the JSON returned:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "hmm.jpg",
          "size": 33096,
          "thumbnail_url": data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSk,   //shortened for brevity
          "type": "image/jpeg",
          "url": "/Home/Download/hmm.jpg",
          "delete_url": "/Home/Delete/hmm.jpg",
          "delete_type": "GET"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "error": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

I've tried with:

- data.result.files
- data.result[0]
- data.result["files"]

and a lot of other even more silly ways. **I have also tried making "result" a single object instead of an array and tried all the above and more without luck.**

Here is a screen capture from my developer console:
[image]

So my question is: how can I access my "files"?

Comment: `data.result[0].files`, like the debugger shows

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined(…), but thanks for the downvote. Please read the question in full, I've already stated that I tried data.result[0] and gotten undefined

Comment: The debugger's output shows that the array exists in `data.result.result[0].files`.

Comment: `data.result.result[0].files` maybe? :P

Comment: You are right gnerkus (and Thomas). I did not notice that at all. Thank you. If you post an answer I will accept.

Comment: A little background: I am not creating the ajax call myself, I'm using jQuery-File-Upload and aspnetboilerplate that might cause the weirdness with result in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer since none of the two guys who gave the correct answer in the comments have posted any answers.

Apparently there was a problem with how the ajax request was handled so the result was not stored in data.result but in data.result.result (which i failed to notice)

So the correct answer to the question is: **data.result.result[0].files**.